# Is there a way to select the contents of COMBOBOX for copy/paste?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

**Problem:** So my application has 2 options, load and update. When I want to update, I also want to copy the content (like Name/UID), but I can't. During update I set "isEnabled=False" (by binding it to a variable) it wont let me copy the content.

I tried doing "isReadOnly=True"(removing the "isEnabled" property), its allowing me to copy, but the DropDown is still working, which will allow me or anyone to change certain values,(like gender, UID) to change during update.

**Goal:** I want to be able to copy the content of the combobox but not letting anyone change its value.

OR

is there a way to disable the dropdown feature so that "isReadOnly=True" would do the trick.

Comment: Even if a combo is disabled you should be able to `Clipboard.SetText(combo.Text);`. - what are you actually trying to do with this Update process? What does "copy the content" mean? What things are you clicking/pressing when you're doing this process?

Comment: for update process, I will let user to change the address, but not his name. I have the same window for load and update, so when its updating, combobox of name and UID "isEnabled is set to false" while letting you to change the address.

Comment: for "copy the content". i meant, select from mouse, press ctrl + C for copy, etc. for textbox i am able to do, but with combobox, i cant.

Comment: sounds like you should put a textbox and a combo box in the same place and show one or the other depending on whether is it s load or an update.. or maybe look into closing the dropdown if the user opens it, but i'd use a readonly textbox instead of a combo

Comment: @AniAxe is you set ComboBoxName.MaxDropDownHeight = 0; while making read-only true user will not able to change the value, and revert it back when you want ? or IsHitTestVisible="False" may work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `isReadOnly=True` is doing what you want, then I will just use a converter to disable the dropdown.

In `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CBMaxDropDownHeightConverter x:Key="CBMaxDropDownHeightConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox MaxDropDownHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource CBMaxDropDownHeightConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then in `CBMaxDropDownHeightConverter.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class CBMaxDropDownHeightConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(value) == true)
            {
                return "0";
            }

            return "Auto";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```